# How to define recursive list type in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, types

I want to create a `flatten` function, which will take List of various depth and transform it to a flat list.

For example, for integers it can take `List(1, List(2, 3))` and return `List(1, 2, 3)`.

How to declare this function correctly?

`def flatten(list: List[???]): List[T]`

Comment: So you want every element of your recursive list to be either type `A` (`Int`, in this case) or `RecursiveList[A]`?

Comment: OK.   Now, since the *title* of your question is "How to define a recursive list type?", I guess you understand that that type has to be created *before* you can create a flatten function.  It's just that the actual text of your question makes no mention of that and only talks about the function.  Would an answer which shows how to create `RecursiveList[A]` and then the function `def flatten[A](xs: RecursiveList[A]): List[A]` be what you want?

Comment: Because you can't arbitrarily create lists that may contain either elements or also lists of elements in Scala (unless you choose Aleksey's solution of `List[Any`).  Scala lists are homogenous.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to use `Any` because the depth of the list is unknown.

```
def flatten(input: List[Any]): List[Any] =
    input match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case head :: tail =>
        head match {
          case list: List[_] => flatten(list) ::: flatten(tail)
          case elem => elem :: flatten(tail)
        }
    }

scala> flatten(List(1, List(2, 3)))
res0: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

If you want to see couple implementation options check [here](https://github.com/izmailoff/scala-s-99/tree/master/src/main/scala/s99/p07), and tests are [here](https://github.com/izmailoff/scala-s-99/blob/master/src/test/scala/s99/p07/P07Suite.scala).

Comment: The problem with this is that it allows input of type List(1, "foo", false) and I'm pretty sure the OP wants all the non-list elements to be the same type.